# How can I change size of y-axis text labels on a likert() object in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, likert

I'm working with the likert() library to generate nice looking diverging stacked bar charts in R. Most of the formatting has come together, but I can't seem to find a way to shrink the text for the y-axis labels (e.g. "You and your family in the UK", "People in your local area..." etc.) which are too large for the plot. Any ideas here? I'm starting to wonder if I need to revert to ggplot, which will require more code, but have more customisability...

```
# Ingest data to make reproducible example:

climate_experience_data <- structure(list(Q25_self_and_family = c(4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 2, 
4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 
3, 2, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2), Q25_local_area = c(3, 
3, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 1, 4, 3, 3, 
4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
4, 3), Q25_uk = c(4, 3, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
5, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 
2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), Q25_outside_uk = c(4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 
4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 
3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-45L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# load libraries:

require(tidyverse)
require(likert)

# Q25 - generate diverging stacked bar chart using likert()
q25_data <- select(climate_experience_data, Q25_self_and_family:Q25_outside_uk)
names(q25_data) <- c("You and your family in the UK", "People in your local area or city", "The UK as a whole", "Your family and/or friends living outside the UK")
# Set up levels text for question responses
q25_levels <- paste(c("not at all", "somewhat", "moderately", "very", "extremely"),  
                    "serious")
q25_likert_table <- q25_data %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                factor, ordered = TRUE, levels = 1:5, labels=q25_levels)) %>% 
  as.data.frame %>%

# make plot:

plot(q25_likert_table, wrap=20, text.size=3, ordered=FALSE, low.color='#B18839', high.color='#590048') + 
  ggtitle(title) +
  labs(title = "How serious a threat do you think \nclimate change poses to the following?", y="") + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL)) + 
  theme_ipsum_rc() +
  theme()
```

Here's a sample of output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your plot is still a ggplot object you could adjust the size of the y axis labels via `theme(axis.text.y = ...)`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(likert)
library(hrbrthemes)

q25_likert_table <- q25_data %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
    factor,
    ordered = TRUE, levels = 1:5, labels = q25_levels
  )) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  likert()

plot(q25_likert_table, wrap = 20, text.size = 3, ordered = FALSE, low.color = "#B18839", high.color = "#590048") +
  ggtitle(title) +
  labs(title = "How serious a threat do you think \nclimate change poses to the following?", y = "") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL)) +
  theme_ipsum_rc() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 4))
```

[image]